# Ask Ubuntu gave question for review when filtered by answers

Tags: bug, review, askubuntu

I sat down to do some routine reviewing this morning, and thought, "Hmm, how about reviewing some answers this morning."

No problem, right?  Apply a filter.  Worked fine, like normal, but after a couple reviews, it turned me up this one:

[image: question, not an answer]

That doesn't look like an answer to me.  :)  At first, I wondered if it was a review audit, (they don't seem to necessarily follow the filters) but it wasn't.  [This is the link](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/653471) to the completed review, if it helps any.

### Edit:

It just happened again.  Here's the screenshot:

[image]